# C# List<T>.ConvertAll in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, list, delegates

I have a list of strings. All of the strings have whitespace that needs to be converted to underscores. I am fully capable of using a `for` or `foreach` loop to do this. I am still relatively new to C# and would like to become more familiar with it. With that said, my question is:

How can I get the following code to work in .NET 2.0? When I check `fieldList` at the end of the `ConvertAll` operation, nothing has changed. Is there an issue with passing the string by value instead of reference?

```
string fields =
  "First Name,Middle Name,Last Name,Birth Date,Gender,Address,City,State,Zip,Email";
List<string> fieldList = new List<string>(fields.Split(','));
fieldList.ConvertAll<string>(new Converter<string, string>(
    delegate(string str)
    {
        str = str.Trim();
        str = str.Replace(' ', '_');
        return str;
    }
));
```

Please, keep in mind, that I am using .NET 2.0 and cannot currently switch, so I do not have the luxury of using LINQ or Lambdas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to assign the results of the `ConvertAll` method to the variable like this:

```
fieldList = fieldList.ConvertAll<string>(new Converter<string, string>(
    delegate(string str)
    {
        str = str.Trim();
        str = str.Replace(' ', '_');
        return str;
    }
));
```

The [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method returns a new `List<T>` so you need to assign the result of the method.  If you want to re-use the `fieldList` variable you can but it may be better to create a new variable to improve the clarity of your code:

```
List<String> convertedFieldList 
    = fieldList.ConvertAll<string>(new Converter<string, string>(
        delegate(string str)
        {
            str = str.Trim();
            str = str.Replace(' ', '_');
            return str;
        }
));
```

As Marc Gravell points out in a comment below, you can simplify the syntax of this expression by doing this:

```
List<String> convertedFieldList 
    = fieldList.ConvertAll<String>(delegate(String str) {
            return str.Trim().Replace(' ', '_');
        });
```

Comment: Just for completeness, you can simplify to `...ConvertAll<string>(delegate (string str) { ... });`

Comment: I got this error:
The type arguments for method 'System.Collections.Generic.List.ConvertAll(System.Converter)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the error.  I am used to using version 4 of the C# compiler :)

Comment: I re-added the new Converter.

fieldList = fieldList.ConvertAll<string>(new Converter<string, string>(
            delegate(string str)
            {
                return str.Trim().Replace(' ', '_');
            }
        ));

Answer (score 3):

`ConvertAll` doesn't change the input list. It returns a new list containing the converted stuff. By the way, you can remove the `new Converter<string,string>` with C# 2.0+:

```
List<string> converted = fieldList.ConvertAll<string>
    (delegate(string s) { return s.Trim().Replace(' ', '_'); });
```

Besides, nothing prevents you from using a C# 3.0 compiler and [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) and target .NET 2.0.

Comment: For some reason, C# 2.0 could not infer the type without the new Converter declaration.